# C# Directory.EnumerateFiles Wrong Ordering

Tags: c#, io, directory

I'm reading some files from a folder with :

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(<folder>, "Client_*.txt"))
{
//Do my stuff
}
```

If I have the files **`Client_999.txt`** and **`Client_1000.txt`** , the **`Client_1000.txt`** file is always processed first.

This always happens with `_9` and `_10`; `_99` and `_100`; `_999` and `_1000`; etc...

Is there any ordering option to make this work?

Comment: [how come nobody uses or does a google search anymore](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20directory.enumeratefiles%20sort) here you can find some examples

Answer (score 3):

If the files are *always* of the form `Client_<number>.txt` then you basically want to sort them according to the parsed number. So write a method to take the original filename, take off the prefix/suffix (or extract the digits with a regex) and then use `int.Parse`. Once you've got that method, you can use `OrderBy` to order the sequence appropriately. Note that at that point using `EnumerateFiles` won't give you any real benefit, as it'll need to get *all* the filenames before it can yield the first one.

Of course, if you can change the filename format, you could format them as `Client_0000.txt` etc - so long as you don't reach 10,000 files, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to explicitly order the files yourself through an `OrderBy` call if you want to get the files in a different order.  `EnumerateFiles` itself won't support any other ordering.